# How to make the model non-transparent

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want retopology a head by using mesh. During the mesh, I found that, the head ist transparent. [image]

How to make the model non-transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your retopology mesh is marked as X-ray. This makes the mesh visible through all other objects.

Uncheck it and all will be fine.

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Have you watermarked the image in your answer? Although the mark is not necessarily obscuring the content, this site is about sharing and linking information, not about self-presentation.